# Replacing while loop with idiomatic functional style

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Below code demonstrates two methods of summing a value where the termination condition is if the value reaches 5 :

```
   object ob extends App {

        def withoutRecursion = {

            var currentTotal = 0.0;

            while(5 > currentTotal){

                currentTotal = currentTotal + scala.util.Random.nextFloat
                println(currentTotal);

            }

        }

        def withRecursion = {

            var currentTotal = 0.0;

            def whileLoop(cond : =>Boolean)(block : =>Unit) : Unit =
                if(cond) {
                    block
                    whileLoop(cond)(block)
                }

            whileLoop(5 > currentTotal) {
                currentTotal = currentTotal + scala.util.Random.nextFloat
                println(currentTotal);
            }

      }

    }
```

Is the `withRecursion` method the idiomatic method of replacing a while loop with a functional programming style in this case ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not really. In your examples you are still using a `var` to collect the intermediate results. That's not very FP.

One (of many) options is to create an infinite, but lazy, `Stream` to repeat the necessary calculations. Then if you want all the intermediate values you `takeWhile()`, or if you want just the end result you `dropWhile()`.

Example:

```
Stream.iterate(0F)(_ + util.Random.nextFloat).takeWhile(_ < 5)
```

This creates a finite `Stream` with all the values from 0.0 to the largest sum less than 5.

On the other hand ...

```
Stream.iterate(0F)(_ + util.Random.nextFloat).dropWhile(_ < 5).head
```

... this will give you the first result greater than 5.